# SQL - How to extract the minimum of all the maximums

Tags: sql

Supposing I have a table "main":

```
CAT  YEAR 
 1   2010
 1   2015
 2   2012
 2   2010
```

I succeed to extract the maximum year by category with:

```
SELECT CAT, MAX(YEAR) FROM main GROUP BY CAT
```

And I would like to get the minimum of the maximum year values, namely 2012 (the third row).

Something like that:

```
SELECT MIN(SELECT MAX(YEAR) FROM main GROUP BY CAT)
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Using your query as a subquery you can select the minimum value of the extracted years from the subquery as follow:

```
select min(year) from    -- Select the minimum year from 
(
    SELECT CAT, MAX(YEAR) as year FROM main GROUP BY CAT
)  -- Your query as subquery
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MIN(yr)
FROM (SELECT CAT, MAX(YEAR) as yr FROM main GROUP BY CAT)
```

This is done using a [subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx).

> A subquery is a query that is nested inside a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement, or inside another subquery. A subquery can be used anywhere an expression is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

One method uses a subquery.  I prefer returning a single row:

```
select cat, max(year)
from main
group by cat
order by max(year) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This allows you to get the `cat` and the `year` in a single query.

Note:  not all databases support the ANSI standard `fetch first 1 row only`.  Some use `limit`, `top` or even other methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use SELECT in SELECT. It's good ways to resolve problem like this.

```
SELECT min(yr)
FROM (SELECT cat, max(YEAR) as yr 
FROM main 
GROUP BY cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already halfway there and can select the minimum value from the table you just created (by using it in the `FROM` part):

```
SELECT MIN(maxYearPerCat) FROM 
  (SELECT CAT, MAX(YEAR) as maxYearPerCatFROM main GROUP BY CAT) as tmpTable
```

[See this SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fee90/3)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT MAX(YEAR) FROM main GROUP BY CAT ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1;
```